# Interceptor, tiles, annotations, and custom includes in JSP files

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, interceptor

## Background

Using tiles in a Spring 3.x application. The application uses a **standard.jsp** file that acts as the web site template, which defines typical elements: doctype, navigation, header, body, etc.

The **standard.jsp** file should dynamically include page-specific customizations. For example, if the URL was "http://localhost/account", then the `<head>` element should contain:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/account.css" />
```

Each tiles definition can be written as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions ...>
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition ...>
        <put-attribute name="viewName" value="account" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Then, in the **standard.jsp** file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<tiles:insertAttribute name="viewName" />.css"/>
```

## Problem

This produces the desired result, but the tiles attributes are hard-coded, effectively duplicated for every tiles.xml file.

## Question

How would you avoid duplicating the `put-attribute` definition everywhere, yet still import specific CSS files that correspond to the view being rendered?

## Idea

Using an Interceptor only works for the `/` URI, and nothing else. For example:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("intro");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(new BaseInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Configuring additional view controllers won't fire the interceptor code:

```
registry.addViewController("/account").setViewName("account");
```

If that worked, then we could iterate over all the JSP files by scanning the classpath (see [here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/MvcConfig.java) and [here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/MvcConfig.java)). The tiles code is probably interfering with the view controller registry for the JSPs:

```
@Bean
public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
    TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml");

    return tilesConfigurer;
}
```

The interceptor is only triggered for `/` and can be used to inject the view name:

```
public class BaseInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        logger.info("BASE INTERCEPTOR POST HANDLE");

        if (modelAndView != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("stylesheet", modelAndView.getViewName() + ".css");
        }

        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```

But because of tiles, the interceptor is never triggered for anything other than `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem right: you have some value that somehow can derived from the view name - right?

My solution (Spring 3.2, Tiles 3) is to use patterns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <!-- base - every thing that is common -->
    <definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/template.jspx">
        ...
    </definition>

    <!-- Tiles view definition for the complete backend --> 
    <definition name="prefix/**" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="mainPart" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="stylesheetUrl" value="/styles/{1}.css" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

That is the only one tiles xml that you need. When you try to render a view with name `prefix/x/y`, then Tiles would load the `/WEB-INF/layouts/template.jspx`
template and set the two attributes:

- mainPart = `/WEB-INF/views/x/y.jsp`
- stylesheetUrl = `/styles/x/y.css`

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: I do not get your problem with the directories (I used this technique with directories) - but maybe the problem is that I do not understand your initial question.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: so there is a prefix needed?

Comment: Yes: the tiles definition cannot match `"*"`, but can match `"flow/*"`.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: "flow/**" should work too - right?

Comment: I imagine so, but we didn't test. For this particular implementation, we're using `flow/*/*` so that we can use `{1}/{2}` for the JSP and `{2}` alone for the CSS/JS artefacts.